# Save excel file multiple times with file names in another workbook.

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small query. I have 2 files.

I want to save 'File#1' multiple times in a specific folder. 
The expected file names are in Sheet1, Column C of 'File#2'. How do I go about it? Any help will be appreciated.

:)

Comment: Please include your code. Also, check out the **[tour]** (you'll get your first badge!) and please see"[ask]" as well as how to create a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Pointing you in the right direction, you'll have to loop through your range and use these values while you save.

Comment: ANY EFFORTS? A-N-Y?? **I down-vote and flag it!!**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code taken from a code I use for something similar - it should help:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Exportmacro()

Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range 'define loop names
Dim NewCaseFile As Workbook 'give a name to new work book for duplicate sheet
Dim wks As Worksheet 'name of the copy of feedback
Dim sPath As String
sPath = MacScript("(path to desktop folder as string)")
'turn off screen
With Application
    '.ScreenUpdating = False  ‘only removed while testing
    '.EnableEvents = False
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  ‘disabled for the moment
End With

'Student numbers in cells A7:A160 WARNING SET TO 3 STUDENTS ONLY FOR TEST
Set rRng = Worksheets("studentlist").Range("A7:A9")

    For Each rCell In rRng '<--| loop through "students" range

        'now open new workbook 
         Set NewCaseFile = Workbooks.Add

        'now save as xls with student number as filename Filename:=sPath & rCell.Value & ".xlsx"
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=rCell.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        'now close duplicate file
         ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Next rCell   '<-- next student number
End With         '<-- once all done
'turn screen back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Provided to get you started - you need to edit / change it to your own needs.